# Jquery on click can't show the data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Please help, I have trouble in this Jquery onclick at my form, Why my data from database can't show ? example, I choose a category "jantung", that should be show data dokter where category is jantung, but if I use onchange at the form it's work.

This is a html where I click the category (if click this category will show the modal)

```html
<?php foreach ($poli as $row): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-6 poliklinik-item">
              <a class="poliklinik-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#poliklinikModal1" onclick="hmm('<?=$row->id_poli?>')">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/upload/<?php echo $row->gambar?>" width="200" height="200">
              </a>
              <div class="poliklinik-caption text-center">
                <h4><?php echo $row->nama_poli; ?></h4>
              </div>
               <br>
               <br>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And This

```js
<script>
function hmm(idnya) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById('poli').value=idnya;
  var id_poli = idnya;
            $('#dokter').prop('disabled',false);
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost/coba/Test/get_autofill",
              type: "POST",
              data: {'id_poli' : id_poli},
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                $('#dokter').html(data);
              },
              error: function(){
                alert('Masih error');
              }
            });
          });
} 
</script>
```

The Modal

```html
<?php echo form_open('hal_user/add/')?>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nama</label>
          <input type="hidden" name="id_pasien" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?=$this->session->userdata('id_pasien') ;?>">

          <input type="text" name="nama_pasien" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('nama_pasien') ; ?>">           
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Poli</label>
              <select name="id_poli" id="poli" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Select Poli</option>
                  <?php foreach ($poli as $p): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $p->id_poli;?>"><?php echo $p->nama_poli;?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Dokter</label>
              <select name="id_dokter" id="dokter" class="form-control" disabled="">
                  <option value="">Select Dokter</option>
              </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tanggal</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Waktu</label>
                <a class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-toggle="collapse" href="#waktuanak" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                  Pilih Waktu
                </a>
              <div class="collapse" id="waktuanak">
                <div class="card card-body">

                  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                   <?php foreach ($waktu as $row) :?>
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                      <input type="radio" name="id_waktu" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $row->id_waktu; ?>"><?php echo $row->waktu;?>  
                    </label>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
         </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-wd">Simpan</button>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('hal_user/'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-wd">Batal</a>
          </div>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Don't have `$(document).ready()` in a function. That's for wrapping code that should be executed when the document is loaded (onload). If you have a function, you shouldn't run that function before that anyway. Also, you say _"but if I use onchange at the form it's work"_ so why don't you just do that?

Comment: I want in this case, the user click icon (category) and show the form where the option poli(category) selected and the option dokter  should be show data from database. So what I should do ? Sorry Im new in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
  **On your view file no need to call function and try to use data-attr and add a class hmm on**

```
<?php foreach ($poli as $row): ?>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-6 poliklinik-item">
       <a class="poliklinik-link hmm" data-toggle="modal" href="#poliklinikModal1" data-attr="<?=$row->id_poli?>">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/upload/<?php echo $row->gambar?>" width="200" height="200">
       </a>
       <div class="poliklinik-caption text-center">
         <h4><?php echo $row->nama_poli; ?></h4>
       </div>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**On your jquery try this**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hmm').on('click',function(){
   var idnya = $(this).attr('data-attr');
   $('#poli').val(idnya );
   var id_poli = idnya;
   $('#dokter').prop('disabled',false);
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/coba/Test/get_autofill",
      type: "POST",
      data: {'id_poli' : id_poli},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
         $('#dokter').html(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Masih error');
      }
   });   
  });
}
```

**Updated**

```
$("#poli option[value='" + idnya+ "']").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: I try to use this, but It's still not working. When I click the icon(category) its not directly selected id_poli. and select option dokter have been show, but I want if the user click the icon, at the form directly selected where user select the icon(category). Sorry for my bad writing.

Comment: On your $('#dokter').html(data); inside succeess on ajax . Try to use console.log(data);) and check you received the data from your ajax file

Comment: the data have been show, but not like I mean. I think for the when the user click the icon, will be automaticly selected the icon category (category) and the data dokter will be show.

Comment: But you not mentioned about icon category or clickable icon on your code

Comment: the poli likes category.

Comment: Trying to be used $('#poli [value=idnya]').attr('selected', 'true'); instead of  $('#poli').val(idnya);

Comment: Nope, I have changed but still like before.

Comment: I have just updated my code . Trying to use this it should work . $("#poli option[value='" + idnya+ "']").prop("selected", true);

Comment: I have trying to use this,but no change.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hmm').on('click',function(){
   var idnya = $(this).attr('data-attr');
   $("#poli option[value='" + idnya+ "']").prop("selected", true);
   var id_poli = idnya;
   $('#dokter').prop('disabled',false);
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/coba/Test/get_autofill",
      type: "POST",
      data: {'id_poli' : id_poli},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
         $('#dokter').html(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Masih error');
      }
   });   
  });
}

Comment: I have been uploaded this on this https://github.com/bimbimadi/ci_reservation 
can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: on xmalang.rar , or  application->views->user->content.php and footer.php

Comment: use $('#dokter').removeAttr('disabled');  instead of $('#dokter').prop('disabled',false); and comment the $('ajax') section for debugging purpose Poli select or not

Comment: I don't know why, still like before.

Comment: you can try it, in my github.com/bimbimadi/ci_reservation  I have xmalang.rar that's the project

Comment: I expect you too to help me :D